# How can I update multiple fields in an array of embedded documents Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

My Mongoose model:

```
const userSchema = Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  books: [{title: String, author: String, isbn: Number}]
});
```

I'd like to add  `a new title & author with a book object` for each POST request. My current approach giving me `positional operator did not find the match` error :

```
var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
router.post('/submit', (req, res) => {    
    let update={
              'books.$.title' : req.body.title,
              'books.$.author' : req.body.author
               }
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body.user_id},{$push: update},{new: true}).exec(function(err, doc) {
      if (err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
     res.send(doc);
    });
});
```

I expect the following result for two form submit(POST) with different author and title in my DB:

```
{
  _id: 'SomeId'
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Cena',
  books: [{title: 'a', author:'b' }, {{title: 'c', author:'d' }}]
}
```

I don't care about ISBN in both post as it's not required field in our schema. Since my `books` sub-document is empty at beginning so I'm not able not set  `positional operator ($)` properly in my code. Please help me to write `findOneAndUpdate` query correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$push` requires field name and value, in your case field name is `book` and value is an object `{author, title}`

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user._id}, {$push : { books : { author: "c", title: "d"}}})
```

Comment: {$push: update} where `update={'books.$.title' : req.body.title , 'books.$.author' : req.body.author}` isn't the same thing??

Comment: Nope, it's not, `books.$.title` means that you have `title` array inside every `book` item.

Comment: Thanks for the help!